# UITapGestureRecognizer not working after UIView frame update

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` and a `navigationItem.titleView`. The titleView has a `UIImageView`, and when tableView scroll, frame size of titleView will update. I also add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView`, so user may view the full image of the `UIImageView`, The issues is default frame size tab gesture works, but when frame size update, it does not work.

- I set the `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.
- I tried to remove the tapGestureReconizer and update it during updating `UIImageView` frame, no luck with this.
- One thing I found, my titleView is `UIView`, and has a subView `UIImageView`, I did not update `UIView` frame Size. Is this causing `UITapGestureRecognizer` not working?